# How to build all CMake targets that depend on a source file?

Tags: cmake

I have a complex build system with dozens of executables and static library targets. I'm trying to figure out a way to tell CMake to build all targets that depend on a specific file from a clean environment. This is to support determining if changes to one source file impact any of the number of libraries and executables that depend on it. For example:

**Target_1** is built with: choco.c, foo.c, bar.c

**Target_2** is built with: choco.c, banana.c

**Target_3** is built with: strawberry.c

My goal is that I can tell cmake "Build all targets that depend on choco.c", and it will automatically build targets 1&2, but not build Target 3.

Are there are any CMake built-ins or tricks to help with this?

Comment: So you want `cmake --build . --target all` to _not_ build other targets that need rebuild but _not_ because of a particular file? If so, interesting. Why?

Comment: If you are okay with a solution that just works for ninja, you may be interested in reading this discussion thread: https://groups.google.com/g/ninja-build/c/cg1RljMLFug

Comment: @DavidFong thanks for the pointer, but unfortunately it looks to be limited to Ninja.

The reason for this is that I want to see how one file change impacts any of the dozens of static libraries, unit tests, and executables. Building everything (particularly from a clean environment) can be a huge time sink if we only really want to see the builds of targets that were impacted by our changes.

Comment: Ah. I see. That point about building from a _clean_ environment is important. I would add it to your question description. Because for incremental rebuilds, usually buildsystems like Ninja and Visual Studio are smart and know what doesn't need to be rebuilt.